# Using a VMWare Appliance with VirtualBox/Parallels

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'd like to use VMWare appliances on my Mac without having to get VMWare Fusion. Is it possible to either port or directly use the VMWare virtual machines with other systems such as Parallels or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article explains how to convert VMWare VMDKs to VirtualBox VDIs:

http://blog.rootshell.be/2009/01/24/vmware-to-virtualbox/

As it states, once the disk image is converted, you'll have to recreate the machine configuration yourself in VirtualBox.